# Encrypting and decrypting data on client side using cryptojs

Tags: javascript, encryption, cryptography, cryptojs

I am working on chrome extension to save some user data to local storage. I encode data with [crypto-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/crypto-js).
However I am facing one minor issue/dilemma - if I encode user data using secret key `abc123` I get something like this `2FsdGVkX19v0LNG0FKFv1SxAQj4AqdNvWWMGyi9yVI=`. However if I decrypt it using another secret key like `abc` I get empty string. Only the correct secret key return non empty string.

So my question how do I need to encode data, if decoding with wrong key it would still return some string? Is there some configuration for this or different encoding?
If I am a hacker and I am using brute force to crack data it looks pretty obvious, what secret key user is using to encode data.

[Fidller](https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-goldwasser-c13fq?file=/src/App.js) to fiddle with configuration.

Comment: You're probably using AES-CBC with PKCS#7 padding. That means that roughly at least 1 in 16 random keys will produce random junk instead of nothing. This is due to padding bytes sometimes working out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Crypto.js you're limited to popular and battle-tested algorithms. Let's say that you're using AES-256-CBC with a key derived from a password ("abc123").

If you encrypt something that a human uses then it likely has low entropy and therefore some structure to it. Think about some JSON string that you're encrypting. If the attacker tries to decrypt the ciphertext with some random key they might get random bytes. If they know they have to get JSON back, they have an oracle whether the decryption worked. They try again with a different key and get different random bytes. They repeat this until they find a plaintext that has a valid JSON structure. Even when they don't know that it is JSON, they might utilize statistical methods in order to deduce whether they got the right key.

You might need to use gzip before encryption in order to make that deduction harder but then the attacker might just incorporate an ungzip procedure in their bruteforcer and just do the statistical analysis.

AES is a block cipher where changing a single bit in the key changes roughly half the bits in the ciphertext with a constant plaintext. That means the attacker will not be able to see that they are getting closer to the correct key. They will have to try all of them.

The usual way of making it harder for an attacker is to increase the work factor. Crypto.js uses by default EVP_bytestokey with a single iteration of a MD5 hash of the password in order to produce the key. This operation is quite fast. You could change that to something like PBKDF2 with a million iterations but today's computers are so fast that this doesn't solve your problem...

The main issue is that your password is too short. "abc123" is a password that can be bruteforced in milliseconds when using Crypto.js defaults (1xMD5) and maybe minutes when using PBKDF2 with a million iterations. Adding a single character to a password multiplies the bruteforce effort by at least 50 (depending on class: upper, lower, digits, special).

Now you can calculate how long your password should be in order interfere with an attacker that corresponds to your risk appetite.

Note that just having encryption doesn't solve all your problems. Usually, the threat still [exists](https://www.nccgroup.com/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score -3):

You only can decrypt your data with the encryption key.
I personally wouldn't encrypt data in a frontend application.

Maybe you should have a look at the documentation:
https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/

Comment: Which part exactly are you recommending to look at?